# apache how to redirect to https protocol from custom port?

Tags: protocols, apache

How can I redirect http://secure.domain.com:444 to https://secure.domain.com:444?

I get 400 (Bad Request) error when I use this code:

```
RewriteEngine
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here's the full config:

```
    Listen 444
    NameVirtualHost ip:444

    <VirtualHost ip:444>
            ServerName secure.domain
            DocumentRoot "/var/www/.phpmyadmin/3.5.1/"

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
            RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

            SSLEngine on
            SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
            SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

            SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/domain.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/domain.pwdless.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
            SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ca.pem

            <Directory "/var/www/.phpmyadmin/3.5.1/">
                    Options None
                    AllowOverride None
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
                    AuthType Basic
                    AuthName "Restriected Access"
                    AuthUserFile "/var/www/.phpmyadmin/.access"
                    Require valid-user
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost ip:444>
            ServerName domain
            ServerAlias *.domain
            RedirectMatch 404 ".*"
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If you don't use a separate port number, how will Apache know whether or not to perform SSL negotiation when there is a connection to the port?

Comment: Actually I do. 444 port has SSL engine enabled. But, I just want to get redirected to https:// if I write http://.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.  The server is setup to only accept SSL requests on that port.  There's an RFC to support what you are asking for (RFC 2817), but it's not supported by the common browsers.  There are some links off the ticket in the [Chrome bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4527).

Comment: This one does redirects from http://isil.monsternett.no:8443/ to https://isil.monsternett.no:8443/.]

Comment: Eh, you are right.  Of course it's possible, but the server has to detect that a non-SSL request is coming in.  I don't believe it's possible with Apache/mod_ssl.  It also seems like there are all sorts of potential security issues with it, but maybe it's no worse than also having port 80 open.